# Finding elapsed time in linear search returns 0 with System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

I am writing a code that is supposed to do a linear search amongst random numbers and return the time used from the search started until the number was found. I read through some of the earlier questions and found out that `System.nanoTime()` is the preferred one.

First I put `INTERVAL = 1000`, and it worked fine. But when I change it to `1 000 000` it just returns `0`, and I don't understand why. How can I solve this problem, or work around it?

```
import java.util.Random;


public class linearSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new linearSearch();
    }

    int[] numbers = new int[1000];
    final int INTERVAL     = 1000000;
    long estimatedTime, searchTime;

    public linearSearch(){
        genererTilfeldig(1000);
        System.out.println("Time to generate the numbers: \t" + estimatedTime+ " nanoseconds");

        System.out.println("\n ---TABLE---");
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers));
        Oppgave3Test.bubbleSort(numbers);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers));

        System.out.println("\n ---Linear search---");
        System.out.println(search(numbers, 4));

        System.out.println("\n ---TIME TO FIND NUMBER---");
        System.out.println("Time to find the number: \t" + searchTime  + " nanoseconds");



    }


    //Generate random numbers
    public void genererTilfeldig(int len){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {


            int randNumb = random.nextInt(INTERVAL);    

            numbers[i] = randNumb;
        }
        estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    }


    public int search(int[] tab, int value){
        long startSearchTime = System.nanoTime();
        int b=-1;                               
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            if(value==tab[i]) {
                b=i;
                searchTime = System.nanoTime() - startSearchTime;
                break;                              
            }

        }
        return b;
      }

}
```

Comment: What value do you think it should have? Why do you think so?

Comment: Also, what affect do you think `INTERVAL` should have on it? Why do you think so?

Comment: It looks like `searchTime` is only set when `if(value==tab[i])` evaluates to true. Thus, if the search can't find the item then you get the default time of 0.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thank you!